# Is there a way to use the service name with wildcard using salt stack?

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a scenario where I have to use service name with wildcard since service name starts with a particular name and it contains the version of software. E.g. in `server-1`, service name is `RunningService14.1.0` and in `server-2`, service name is `RunningService15.2.0`.

How can I pass the service name dynamically?

Below syntax is not working.

start_service:

```yaml
service.start:

- name: RunningServ*
```

Where as below syntax is working fine.

status_service:

```yaml
service.status:

- name: RunningServ*
```

Comment: <not a salt-stack expert>I would say, this comes from the way services managers works, when you can filter `RunningServ*` on a finite list of running services to have their status, you cannot guess the service unit file to run on with a wildcard because there Is an infinite number of possibilities as unit are just files</not a salt-stack expert>. This said, if I was to face the same use case in Ansible, which I am using, I would first list the services or the service units files and then filter the said list with `RunningServ*`, in order to run it in a subsequent task.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the service status with wildcard because the `service.status` module supports it. Quoting from documentation:

> Return the status for a service. If the name contains globbing, a dict mapping service name to True/False values is returned.

But the same is not true for the `service.start` module, which requires a specific service name.

To avoid using the wildcard, you could keep the version of software in a [pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/getstarted/config/pillar.html) or custom grain for each server. Example for `server-1`:

```yaml
software_version: "14.1.0"
```

Then your state file can be simple and just have:

```yaml
start-service:
  module.run:
    - service.start:
        - name: RunningService{{ software_version }}
```

This will ensure that the appropriate version is picked up for each server, and the corresponding service will be started.

Otherwise, as @β.εηοιτ.βε suggested in his comment, we can get all services, filter and take action only when service name contains `RunningServ`. Though this will require writing logic in the state file.

```
{% set all_services = salt['service.get_all']() %}

{% for service_name in all_services %}
{% if 'RunningServ' in service_name %}
start-service-{{ service_name }}:
  module.run:
    - service.start:
        - name: {{ service_name }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```